# Keras custom loss function doesn't update my layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get an embedding of some data I have using Keras. I have a model consisting of only an embedding layer, and then I have my own custom loss function that uses the weights of the embedding layer to calculate a loss function, however, the network won't train at all, meaning the loss value is always the same.

My loss function looks like this

```
def custom_loss(a,b):
    layer = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
    distances = [distance(layer[i],layer[j]) for i in range(len(layer)-1) for j in range(i+1, len(layer))]
    loss = [-math.log10(sims[i]*distances[i])for i in range(len(sims))]
    return K.sum(loss)+0*K.sum(b)

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",loss=custom_loss)
```

I get the distances between the different n-dimensional embedding values for all different points I pass to the embedding layer. I have the `+0*K.sum(b)` because otherwise, I get a no gradient exception. `sims` is a list of values that I multiply the distances with. `loss` ends up being a list with floats.

I don't get any exceptions, however, the loss is just constant. What might be wrong? 
I must say I'm not really familiar with creating custom loss functions like this in Keras, so what I've done might be totally wrong.

My training data consists of simply passing ones as input values, as I'm, again, only interested in getting the embedding wrt my custom loss function. I know I'm basically abusing Keras in order to not write my own optimization function.

Does my `K.sum(loss)` simply give no gradient? My intuition tells me that `layer = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]` is simply not updated between batches, but I don't know if this is correct, or if it is, how to fix it. Is there some other way to access the weights that would work?

Network summary looks like this

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 400, 3)            1200      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,200
Trainable params: 1,200
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The distance function used looks like this

```
def distance(a,b):
    powers = [(a[i]-b[i])**2 for i in range(len(a))]
    return math.sqrt(sum(powers))
```

Comment: You cannot implement a loss using numpy or plain python functions, you have to use backend functions. Your loss is effectively constant due to this, giving zero gradients.

Comment: Adding to Matias Valdenegro's: the following is numpy: `layer = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]`, if you want the tensor you should go for `model.layers[0].embeddings`.